# Facebook/Gmail/Twitter Connection with Unity3D

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter, gmail, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3D application who needs registration.
The user needs to register in the application. He can simply enter an email adress and a password. Those are used to access the application.
But i want to offer the possibility to connect with other existing account like facebook, gmail, twitter...
Is it possible ? Everything must be in the Unity App but can use http request.

Comment: Is this going to run in the browser?

Comment: Yes, but there's only unity displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning **Unity/Facebook**, I used a very good tutorial:
http://www.paladinstudios.com/2011/11/15/facebook-and-unity-tutorial-part-one/
http://www.paladinstudios.com/2011/11/24/facebook-and-unity-tutorial-part-two/
http://www.paladinstudios.com/2011/12/06/facebook-and-unity-tutorial-part-three/
It uses the JavaScript Facebook Api and the usefull functions :

```
<UNITY> Application.ExternalCall("YourJavaFunction");
<JS>    getUnity().SendMessage("YourGameObject", "YourUnityFunction", yourdata);
```

Concerning **Unity/Twitter** I didn't found a way to directly contact Twitter with Unity. But I use TweetSharp with my asp.net c# Backend.
https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp
https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

Give these links a try. I've not yet gotten around to integration with other federated systems, but I believe these links will give you most of what you need to get it started.

- [Google's Federated Login API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)
- [Facebook's OAuth Integration (for Unity)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/64332-Facebook-OAuth-API-how-to-add-Facebook-integration-into-your-desktop-game-%28-source%29)
- [Example of Twitter OAuth in Unity (that was not working for an unrelated reason)](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/44489/post-data-via-wwwform-is-not-working-for-twitter-o.html)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook integration is going to be added in for iOS 6. In addition to the twitter integration they already have. It may be worth it to wait to implement this feature until there's a unity wrapper for the iOS 6 feature. Though, you'd still have do to something different for google.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to build a Web App.